# use of if and else in a while loop

Tags: c++

all the code is working fine, but when else is implemented the programme closes, i want that code should again ask for input, help needed!

```
 #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int total;    // this is the number which is the multiple of 10
  cout<<"Enter a number = ";
  cin>>total;

  while(total!=-1)  
  {

    if (total % 10 == 0) 
    {        
      total=total-10;
      total=total/5;
      cout<<"total= "<< total<<endl;

      cout<<"1st number= "<<total<<endl;
      cout<<"2nd number= "<<total+1<<endl;
      cout<<"3rd number= "<<total+2<<endl;
      cout<<"4th number= "<<total+3<<endl;
      cout<<"5th number= "<<total+4<<endl;
      break;    
    }
    else 
    {
      cout<<"re-enter the number"<<endl;    
      break;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please format the code correctly (fix the indentation)

Comment: See this [reference on break](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break).

Comment: You should move your 'return 0' statement to the end of your main() since it is the signal that the execution of your program was successful

Answer (score 4):

Remove `break;` from else cause and add `cin>>total;`

```
else 
{
    cout<<"re-enter the number"<<endl;  
    cin>>total;

}
```

Comment: @user3152720 Please never say "it doesn't work" without saying *how* it doesn't work. Compilation error? Linker error? Behaviour (describe!) different from what you expect (also describe!)?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan you could also put the `cin >> total` at the start of loop and `return 0` outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `break;` statement from the `else` clause. `break;` causes the nearest enclosing loop (or switch) to exit, which in your case is the `while()` loop.

Also, you will have to ask for input again in such case, so read in `total` again in the `else` branch.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `break;` causes program control to exit the innermost loop containing the `break`. Therefore in your case it causes the `while` to complete.

I think you're confusing your `if` block with the syntax for a `switch`. In a `switch` block, `break`s are indeed necessary to avoid the default *follow through* behaviour of individual `case` statements.

You probably also need to reposition your `return 0;` statement too: that will cause the program to exit, returning `0` back to the command shell.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `break` you should use `continue` here, which will go to the top of the loop. You have a return statement as well inside the loop, so the `continue` will skip this. Either that, or you must remove the `return` as well , and you need a return for `main` as well.